# std::regex, to match begin/end of string

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, std, multiline

In JS regular expressions symbols `^` and `$` designate **start and end of the string**. And only with `/m` modifier (multiline mode) they match **start and end of line** - position before and after CR/LF.

But in [std::regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/)/ECMAscript mode symbols `^` and `$` match **start and end of line** always.

Is there any way in std::regex to define **start and end of the string** match points? In other words: to support JavaScript multiline mode ...

Comment: The point is that `^` and `$` match the start and end of string. See https://ideone.com/amatBf and https://ideone.com/0D7eS7

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok, how to modify your samples for `^` and `$` to match  start/end of line ?

Comment: I already mentioned: for the end of line, it is `(?=\n|$)`, for the start of line it can only be a consuming pattern like `(^|\n)`. This is very uncomfortable, I know. Switching to Boost regex might turn out the best option if you really need that multiline behavior for `^` / `$`.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR**

- MSVC: the `^` and `$` already match start and end of *lines*
- C++17: [use](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript) [`std::regex_constants::multiline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type) option
- Other compilers only match start of string with `^` and end of string with `$` with no a possibility to redefine their behavior.

---

In all `std::regex` implementations other than MSVC and before C++17, the `^` and `$` match beginning and end of the *string*, not a line. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/g1Oe5R) that does not find any match in `"1\n2\n3"` with `^\d+$` regex. When you add alternations (see below), [there are 3 matches](https://ideone.com/L9yRwz).

However, in MSVC and C++17, the `^` and `$` may match start/end of the *line*.

**C++17**

Use the [`std::regex_constants::multiline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type) option.

**MSVC compiler**

In a C++ project in Visual Studio, the following

```
std::regex r("^\\d+$");
std::string st("1\n2\n3");
for (std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(st.begin(), st.end(), r);
    i != std::sregex_iterator();
    ++i)
{
    std::smatch m = *i;
    std::cout << "Match value: " << m.str() << " at Position " << m.position() << '\n';
}
```

will output

```
Match value: 1 at Position 0
Match value: 2 at Position 2
Match value: 3 at Position 4
```

**Workarounds that work across C++ compilers**

There is no *universal* option in `std::regex` to make the anchors match start/end of the line across all compilers. You need to emulate it with alternations:

```
^ -> (^|\n)
$ -> (?=\n|$)
```

Note that `$` can be "emulated" fully with `(?=\n|$)` (where you may add more line terminator symbols or symbol sequences, like `(?=\r?\n|\r|$)`), but with `^`, you cannot find a 100% workaround.

Since there is no lookbehind support, you might have to adjust other parts of your regex pattern because of `(^|\n)` like using capturing groups more often than you could with a lookbehind support.

Comment: I think my wording is a bit hectic, but what I am driving at is that your initial presumptions are wrong. The `^` only matches the beginning of a string, and `$` only matches the end of the string.

Comment: "The assertion ^ (beginning of line) matches the position that immediately follows a LineTerminator character...."  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript

Comment: @c-smile: I know what you mean but my answer is based on practical experience.

Comment: If there is a need to support CR (carriage return), then `^ -> (^|[\r\n])` and `$ -> (?=\r?\n|$)` / `(?=[\r\n]|$)`

Answer (score 6):

By default, ECMAscript mode already treats `^` as both beginning-of-input *and* beginning-of-line, and `$` as both end-of-input *and* end-of-line. There is no way to make them match *only* beginning or end-of-input, but it is possible to make them match *only* beginning or end-of-line:

When invoking [`std::regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match), [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search), or [`std::regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace), there is an argument of type [`std::regex_constants::match_flag_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_flag_type) that defaults to `std::regex_constants::match_default`.

- To specify that `^` matches only beginning-of-line, specify `std::regex_constants::match_not_bol`
- To specify that `$` matches only end-of-line, specify `std::regex_constants::match_not_eol`
- As these values are bitflags, to specify both, simply bitwise-or them together (`std::regex_constants::match_not_bol | std::regex_constants::match_not_eol`)
- Note that beginning-of-input can be implied without using `^` and regardless of the presence of `std::regex_constants::match_not_bol` by specifying `std::regex_constants::match_continuous`

This is explained well in the [ECMAScript grammar documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript) on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/), which I highly recommend over cplusplus.com in general.

Caveat: I've tested with MSVC, Clang + libc++, and Clang + libstdc++, and only MSVC has the correct behavior at present.

Comment: From your link cppreference.com

The assertion ^ (beginning of line) matches
1) The position that immediately follows a LineTerminator character. (if supported, see LWG issue 2343)
2) The beginning of the input (unless std::regex_constants::match_not_bol(C++ only) is enabled)

That's quite different from what is needed. 

I need `^` to match just "the beginning of the input" and nothing else.

Comment: @c-smile : Quite right, I grossly misread it. Answer updated.

Comment: My mental parser fails to parse:
"To specify that $ matches only end-of-line, specify std::regex_constants::match_**not**_eol"

As for me `match_not_eol` shall mean quite opposite thing:  if that flag is set then it shall not match EOL, only end of input, right ? And that really makes sense.  

In the way you interpret it that flag is useless.

Comment: @c-smile : It means "don't treat `first` as BOL or `last` as EOL", _not_ what you want. I linked to the documentation for a reason. ;-]

Comment: Not clear what "first" and "last" mean here. Anyway, the question is: 
What flags to use for `^` to match only beginning-of-input (same with `$` and end-of-input) ? In boost there are explicit `\A` and `\z`  markers that match explicitly head/tail of the input :http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/regex/doc/syntax.html  
seems like std lost this feature.

Comment: @c-smile : `first` and `last` are the iterator-range passed in to the regex algorithm (search, match, replace). I don't think `std::regex` supports what you want with ECMAScript syntax, but POSIX syntax may have what you want. I'm not exhaustively familiar with these, but cppreference.com has links to their grammars.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet matches email addresses starting [a-z] followed by 0 or 1 dot, then by 0 or more a-z letters, then ending with "@gmail.com". I tested it.

```
string reg = "^[a-z]+\\.*[a-z]*@gmail\\.com$";

regex reg1(reg, regex_constants::icase);
reg1(regex_str, regex_constants::icase);
string email;
cin>>email;
if (regex_search(email, reg1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate Perl/Python/PCRE `\A`, which matches at beginning of string but not after a newline, with the Javascript regex `^(?<!(.|\n)])`, which translates to English as "match the beginning of a line which has no preceding character".

You can emulate Perl/Python/PCRE `\z`, which matches only at end-of-string, using `(?!(.|\n))$`. To get the effect of `\Z`, which matches only at end-of-string but allows a single newline just before that end-of-string, just add an optional newline: `\n?(?!(.|\n))$`.