# std::regex doesn't recognize $

Tags: c++, regex, stl, posix

I try to parse the content of the file with a regex:

```
ifstream file_stream("commented.cpp",ifstream::binary);

std::string txt((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file_stream)),
std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

cmatch m;
bool result = regex_search(txt.c_str(), m, regex("^#(\S*)$",regex_constants::basic));
```

The file is a c source, and it begins with the line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

I'm trying to parse a directive, i checked the regexp in regexbuddy and it works 100%, but in std::regex `regex_search` returns false. It seems that `$` character is not gettinc recognized and also `^` for the `posix` syntax. I have tried to use `ECMAScript`, and the regex works, only if i remove `$` symbol.

```
//ecmascript syntax
bool result = regex_search(txt.c_str(), m, regex("^#(\S*)"));
```

The file is read using binary flag, so the `txt` string, keeps all `\r\n` characters which are required for `$` syntax. I look for help, how to resolve this issue.

Comment: But `^#(\S*)$` _doesn't_ match `#include <stdio.h>`.  `\S` only matches non-whitespace.  There's whitespace in `#include <stdio.h>`, and you can't match `#include` with that regex because `$` wants to anchor on the end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `$` anchor in most cases works only as an end-of-string (whole input) anchor. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645660/stdregex-to-match-begin-end-of-string). You may make `$` match end of a line position by using a custom boundary pattern based on a positive lookahead, `(?=$|\r?\n)`.

Another issue is that you are using `\S` escape sequence in a regular string literal. That means, it is treated as an `S` letter, not as a non-whitespace pattern. Use a raw string literal so that you could use a single `\` to define a *regex* escape sequence (where `\` escaping `d`, `s`, etc. should be literal backslashes). Or double escape `\` in regular string literals.

Also, @HWalters already noted that the `^#\S+$` will not match `#include <stdio.h>`, you need to account for a space inside. Thus, you regex might look like `^#include[ \t]+(\S+)(?=$|\r?\n)`, to make sure you have `#include`, then some horizontal spaces, and then capture any number (1 or more here, with `+`) of non-whitespace chars up to the end of string or a line break (CRLF or LF).

And here is a [snippet](https://ideone.com/MUx80I):

```
regex r(R"(^#include[ \t]+(\S+)(?=$|\r?\n))");
string s("#include <stdio.h>\r\n#include <regex>");
smatch m;
if (regex_search(s, m, r)) {
    std::cout << m[1] << std::endl;
}
```