# Make dollar and caret only match at beginning/end of string, not before/after embedded newlines

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, boost, multiline

This little code which follows outputs

```
<hello>
<world>
```

demonstrating that `^` and `$` are also matching after and before of `\n` respectively. How can I change this behavior, and have them only match at beginning and end of string? (In this case, there would be no match in the example `str` input.)

```cpp
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::string tokenRegex = "^[^\n\r]+$";
    std::string str = "hello\nworld";
    boost::sregex_iterator rit{std::begin(str), std::end(str), boost::regex{tokenRegex}};
    boost::sregex_iterator end;

    while (rit != end) {
        std::cout << '<' << rit->str() << '>' << '\n';
        ++rit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, the linked question is asking about std::regex not boost::regex. I voted to reopen this.

Comment: Thank you, however the answer is likely contained in one comment of [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39645780/5825294). Tomorrow at work I'll check if `\z` works as explained in that comment. If so, then that comment is the answer and should be copied here as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`match_single_line` flag](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/match_flag_type.html):

```
boost::sregex_iterator rit{
    std::begin(str),
    std::end(str),
    boost::regex{tokenRegex},
    boost::match_single_line // <-- here
};
```

This is a match flag - you specify it when matching (or constructing an iterator which matches), not when compiling the regex.